# How to prevent JPA rollback exception after insertion?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, persistence

ECard:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "ecard")
public class Ecard {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdUser", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdBank", nullable = false)
    private Bank bank;

    @Column (name = "accountNumber", nullable = false)
    private int accountNumber;

    public ECard(User user, Bank bank, int accNumber) {
       this.user = user;
       this.bank = bank;
       this.accountNumber = accNumber;
    }
}
```

User:

```
     @Entity
    @Table (name="user")
    public class User {
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @OneToOne (mappedBy = "user")
        private ECard eCard;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinTable(
            name = "ecard", 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IdBank", referencedColumnName = "Id"),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IdUser", referencedColumnName = "Id")
        )
        private Bank bank;

public void seteCard(ECard eCard) {
        this.eCard = eCard;
    }

    public void setBank(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }
}
```

Bank:

```
    @Entity
    @Table (name = "bank")
    public class Bank {
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String name;
}
```

I have already initialized Bank table and I would like to insert new User with new ECard linked to Bank that already exists in database

I'm new to this whole thing so I can't understand why

My code that won't work:

```
        //I checked and variable bank is okay, it's method argument
        eManager.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = new User();
        ECard eCard = new ECard(user, bank, 1000);

        user.seteCard(eCard);
        user.setBank(bank); // PROBLEM
        eManager.persist(eCard);

        eManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get a rollback Exception:

```
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'accountNumber' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO ecard (IdBank, IdUser) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="bank" sql="INSERT INTO ecard (IdBank, IdUser) VALUES (?, ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(StatementQueryMechanism.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.performDataModificationEvent(OneToOneMapping.java:2181)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4200)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1439)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'accountNumber' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:885)
    ... 34 more
Java Result: 1
```

When i delete line `user.setBank(bank)` it works great, but I need reference on Bank in User, so deleting this line isn't so good for me.

When I put default value for accountNumber, I get two rows in eCard table, one regular row and second row with default accountNumber and same IdUser and IdBank

How to avoid that exception and how to set reference on Bank??

Comment: Can you show us the database schema this might be a problem with the Bank definition in your Database. I had that kind of problems and most of the time the primary key is not defined correctly in the problematic entity. Or the auto increment flag is missing. Or more precisely the Bank table description.

Comment: accountNumber does not have a value. The line you mention does seem to affect that field

Comment: Also check the accountNumber is a valid accountNumber. Since accountNumber is an int it must be present and can not be set to Null.

Comment: Schema : http://i66.tinypic.com/34ispd2.png , 'naziv' is name, because schema is in my native language. This problem with accNumber is strange because it tries to put two rows in eCard, I don't know why. Here is regular integer argument in constructor for accNumber, so it isn't null.

Comment: I added default value to column accountNumber and I avoided exception but it gave me two rows in eCard and second row with default value for accountNumber and same values for IdUser and IdBank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already declaring `ecard` as your mapping table by adding this

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "ecard", 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IdBank", referencedColumnName = "Id"),
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IdUser", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    )
```

But `ecard` is also used as an entity to map information of user and bank by associating bankId and userId  plus an accountNumber field.
That's why Jpa is adding 2 record in persist of user - one for defined mapping in user class `name = 'ecard'` mapping and one for the `ECard eCard = new ECard(user, bank, 1000);`

I would suggest you move accountNumber field to bank class and delete `ecard` class because mapping in `JoinColumn (name = 'ecard'...` already assumes there exists a table `ecard` with just 2 columns userId and bankId  and  would handle it in default way.

Or remove the bank field in user class because user already has reference to `ecard` which has reference to `bank`.But now you will have to manage the association between bank and user manually like you are doing it in above code.

Comment: The only drawback I see with deleting the card class is that you end up having a table without mapping. If you map it later you need to make sure you don't fall into this again